# Strange compiler error with Dictionary<String, String>

Tags: swift

I'm not sure if I'm being an idiot or there is a compiler bug in the current Swift compiler but...

I declare a function into which I pass a `Dictionary<String, String>`, in that method I attempt to add an item into the `Dictionary`, the method is

```
func writeStatus(res: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    res["key"] = "value"
}
```

and I get the compiler error

```
'@lvalue $T5 is not identical to '(String, String)'
```

In the method the `Dictionary` is declared in i can add items fine. So my question is how to I add items into a dictionary in a function? I could do all this in the line function but I hate functions that do too much.

I am using the Swift compiler in Xcode 6.2 beta if that's any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is more helpful, but if you want the dictionary to be mutated, it might be an idea to use an `inout` argument:

```
func addDict(inout res: [String: String]) {
    res["key"] = "value"
}

var res = [String: String]()
addDict(&res)
println(res) // [key: value]
```

This doesn't have any errors, and `res` will have the values assigned to it in the `addDict` function.

Answer (score 1):

By default all function parameters are immutable. So if you try to mutate them you will get compiler error. If you want to mutate function parameter define it as `var`.

```
func writeStatus(var res: [String: String]) {
    res[key] = "value"
}
```

But here it will not work. Because `Dictionary` is value type and value types are copied when they are passed into a function. And your mutation will only have affect on copied value. So in this senario defining parameter as `inout` will solve your problem